# VS 2022 not launching Swagger in browser until Quartz background job is finished

Tags: c#, .net-core, quartz.net

I am writing a simple application that will expose an API and that runs some background jobs using `Quartz`. The application has to run a fetching job and then a checking job repeatedly. When I launch from `VS 2022`, Chrome is not starting with the swagger page until the checking job finishes its first iteration.

It is not something that concerns me too much, but it is annoying. I can open `Swagger` manually. I am adding my jobs this way:

```
public sealed class CachingBackgroundJob : IJob
{
    private readonly ISchedulerService _schedulerService;

    public CachingBackgroundJob(ISchedulerService schedulerService)
    {
        _schedulerService = schedulerService;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        await _schedulerService.FillCache(context.CancellationToken);
    }
}
```

```
public sealed class SchedulingBackgroundJob : IJob
{
    private readonly ISchedulerService _schedulerService;

    public SchedulingBackgroundJob(ISchedulerService schedulerService)
    {
        _schedulerService = schedulerService;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        await _schedulerService.CheckHealth(context.CancellationToken);
    }
}
```

These are the jobs. Then, I wrote the following DI method:

```
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static void AddScheduler(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddQuartz(opts =>
        {
            var cachingBackgroundJobKey = JobKey.Create(nameof(CachingBackgroundJob));
            opts.AddJob<CachingBackgroundJob>(cachingBackgroundJobKey)
                .AddTrigger(trigger =>
                {
                    trigger.ForJob(cachingBackgroundJobKey)
                        .WithSimpleSchedule(schedule =>
                        {
                            schedule.WithRepeatCount(0);
                        });
                });
            var matcher = KeyMatcher<JobKey>.KeyEquals(cachingBackgroundJobKey);
            opts.AddJobListener<CachingJobCompletionListener>(matcher);
        });

        services.AddQuartzHostedService();
    }
}
```

And the listener for when the first job ends:

```
internal class CachingJobCompletionListener : IJobListener
{
    public string Name => "CachingBackgroundJobCompletedListener";

    public Task JobExecutionVetoed(IJobExecutionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task JobToBeExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task JobWasExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException? jobException, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var scheduler = context.Scheduler;
        var schedulingBackgroundJobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(schedule =>
            {
                schedule.WithIntervalInMinutes(1);
                schedule.RepeatForever();
            })
            .StartNow()
            .Build();

        var jobDetail = JobBuilder
            .Create()
            .OfType<SchedulingBackgroundJob>()
            .WithIdentity(JobKey.Create(nameof(SchedulingBackgroundJob)))
            .DisallowConcurrentExecution()
            .Build();

        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, schedulingBackgroundJobTrigger, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Any ideas of why this is blocking the launching of the browser by `VS 2022`?
Thank you.

EDIT: `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);

IConfiguration redisConfiguration = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Caching");
string connectionString = redisConfiguration["redis"]!;
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>((serviceProvider) => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString));

ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);

builder.Services.AddScoped<ISchedulerService, SchedulerService>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddScheduler();

builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, config) =>
{
    config.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
});

var applicationAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("Example.Application");

builder.Services
    .AddMediatR(opts => opts.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(applicationAssembly))
    .AddFluentValidationAutoValidation()
    .AddValidatorsFromAssembly(applicationAssembly);
ValidatorOptions.Global.DefaultRuleLevelCascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop;

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Please share your Program.cs codes, specially the middleware pipeline.

Comment: done @S.M.JAHANGIR

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas of why this is blocking the launching of the browser by VS
> 2022?

If you take a  look at this statement `services.AddQuartzHostedService();` it's basically registering an `IHostedService` of type [QuartzHostedService](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/main/src/Quartz/Hosting/QuartzServiceCollectionExtensions.cs).
And with `IHostedServices` this is the default behaviour and is by design with **.NET 6** when you call `app.run` all your hosted services are started before the Kestrel web server starts.

> The ordering is different when using the WebApplicationBuilder and
> services IHostedService instances always run before the server starts.

[Issue #38698](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38698#issuecomment-988577992)

**Final Thoughts**

You need to evaluate if `CachingBackgroundJob` and `SchedulingBackgroundJob` need to be started before the Kestrel server runs that will inform your decision, If you prefer these jobs to start after the app is running then I personally albeit with some bias would prefer [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) in this scenario.

Comment: So there's no way of achieving this with Quartz but there is a way with Hangfire you mean?

Comment: Quartz is leveraging the `IHostedService` basically  it will execute before your web api runs I would use this if I needed the service to do some initiation tasks before the web server runs. I donot see any logic of `Quartz`  that allows starting services spontaneously  and anywhere in your app  like Hangfire.